# MS Word VBA, trying to populate a combobox with data from an http call

Tags: vba, http, combobox, ms-word

I'm using the following code to populate a combobox in Word 2003.

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
ComboBox1.List = Array("Red", "Green", "Yellow", "Blue")
End Sub
```

What I would like to do is get the data dynamically via an http call. This other function seems to work to get data via http

```
Dim MyRequest As Object

Set MyRequest = CreateObject("WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5.1")
MyRequest.Open "GET", _
"http://localhost:8500/test7.htm"

' Send Request.
MyRequest.Send

'And we get this response
MsgBox MyRequest.ResponseText
```

test7.htm just contains

```
"Red", "Green", "Yellow", "Blue"
```

I was hoping to combine the two but below doesn't work

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
Dim MyRequest As Object

Set MyRequest = CreateObject("WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5.1")
MyRequest.Open "GET", _
"http://localhost:8500/test7.htm"

' Send Request.
MyRequest.Send


ComboBox1.List = Array(MyRequest.ResponseText)
End Sub
```

Any help for a VBA noob appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The **response text** should be a *simple comma separated string*, something like

> Red,Green,Yellow,Blue

Thus you can use the following method for populating the ComboBox:

```
Private Sub populateComboBox(ByRef combo As ComboBox, ByRef html As String)
    Dim arrayValues() As String, index As Integer
    arrayValues = Split(Trim(html), ",")
    For index = LBound(arrayValues) To UBound(arrayValues)
        combo.AddItem (arrayValues(index))
    Next
End Sub
```

For calling the method you can use the following sentence.

```
Call populateComboBox(Combo1, MyRequest.ResponseText)
```